# Launching batch file from within HTA

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, hta

I'm trying to launch a batch file from within a HTA file. The launching of the batch file appears to start properly (or at least the associated CMD prompt), but the batch closes moments later, when it should take approximately 5 minutes. During the brief moment the CMD process is running, HTA window appears to pause, then closes as soon as the CMD process ends. Everything else about the HTA functions properly.

The goal is to have the HTA launch the batch file in the background (hidden) and while the batch file is processing, have no affect on the HTA. Once the batch file has completed and exited, the HTA will launch a new HTA with information for the user.

Here's the HTA I have that is not functioning properly...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { background:#fff url('../_dependencies/welcome.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; color:#000; margin:25px; padding:0; }
      div#gap { height:306px; }
      div#buttons { padding-right:12px; position:absolute; right:0; }
    </style>
    <title>Installer</title>
    <script language="vbscript">
      Sub Window_OnLoad
        Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        sPath = Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%curdir%")
        Continue = Chr(34) & sPath & "_install.cmd" & Chr(34)
        Shell.Run Continue,0,True
        CompName = Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%computername%")
        Const ForAppending = 8
        textFile = sPath & "_Logs\" & CompName & ".upgraded.txt"
        If Not objFSO.FileExists(textFile) Then
          Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(textFile, True)
          objTextFile.Close
        End If
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.opentextfile(textFile,ForAppending)
        objTextFile.WriteLine("Upgrade complete on this computer." & vbCrLf & Now())
        objTextFile.Close
        Set textFile = Nothing
        self.close()
      End Sub
    </script>
    <script language="javascript">
      window.resizeTo(620,365);
      window.moveTo((screen.width-620)/2,(screen.height-365)/2);
    </script>
    <hta:application applicationname="Installer" border="none" caption="no" id="objnotitlebar" innerborder="no" maximizebutton="no" minimizebutton="no" scroll="no" showintaskbar="no" singleinstance="yes" systemmenu="no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gap"><img src="../_dependencies/waiting.gif" /></div>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post also the source code of `install.cmd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bit of troubleshooting, the issue in the batch script was a misconfigured start statement.

The start statement was this:

```
@start /b /min /wait "upgradeinstaller.exe" /silent /noreboot
```

I changed it to this:

```
@start /b /min /wait "Upgrade Installer" "upgradeinstaller.exe" /silent /noreboot
```

I apparently needed to add the title to the start command, otherwise the start command thought the first quoted text was the title, then the switches were applied to start, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't provide an environment variable `%curdir%`. Its expansion produces a literal string `%curdir%`, so the Command Prompt probably closes immediatly because a file `%curdir%_install.cmd` cannot be found. Did you perhaps mean `%cd%`? That variable is only available within CMD.

And do you actually want to run the script from the current working directory in the first place? I'd say it's more likely that you mean to run the batch file from the same directory as the HTA. That location can be determined like this:

```
dir = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Replace(document.location.href, "file:///", ""))
sPath = objFSO.GetFolder(dir).Path
```

If that doesn't help change the line

```
Shell.Run Continue,0,True
```

into this:

```
Shell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k " & Continue, 1, True
```

Running a batch script with `cmd /k` keeps the Command Prompt open after the (attempted) script execution, so you can see if there were any errors.

Comment: The variable %curdir% is pre-populated with the value of %~dp0. When I msgbox that variable, it does display correctly. As for the batch file, it is located in one directory up from where the HTA file is located. As for your suggestion, I made the change to the Shell.Run command, and now I can see the CMD window open, but it is simply sitting at a prompt and not running the batch file and the animation that should be playing on the HTA screen is paused for as long as the CMD prompt remains open.

Comment: Do you get the same effect with a batch file that contains just the line `@echo hello`?

Comment: Nope. A simple batch file with just echo hello, followed by a pause, displays just fine and dandy. I wonder if it is because of the calls to different batch files within the original batch files? I'm going to perform some more testing to find out. Thanx.

Comment: Then the issue is with the batch script you're running, not with your HTA.

Comment: I thought so as well, but if I run the batch script on it's own, outside of the HTA, it runs without error or issue. It is only when it is called from within the HTA that this behavior is encountered. Perhaps HTAs just can't process some of the commands within the batch script?

Comment: Unlikely. Without seeing your batch file (and prefereably the one you use to launch the HTA as well) there's nothing else I could tell you, though.

Comment: It will take some time for me to edit the batch files to omit sensitive data prior to posting them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124992/discussion-between-user3208239-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Comment: Now the only issue that needs to resolved is when the installer is running, hidden in the background, the animation freezes on the HTA window unless the mouse pointer runs over it.